# Subset of samples has any effect on sufficiency of the statistic?

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference, estimation

If we have the following iid samples
$$
X_1, ..., X_n  \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) 
$$
where only $\mu$ is unknown. We know one sufficient statistic is the following: 
$$
T = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$
Also define the following statistic: 
$$
T_1(k) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k X_i
$$
Are the followings sufficient statistics?

(1) $T_1(k)$ when $k = n-c$, where $c$ is a constant integer.

(2) $T_1(k)$ when $k = c$, where $c$ is a constant integer.

Is the result here generalizeable to other distributions (with their proper statistics)?

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same statement, and $(2)$ is trivially not true---take $k = 1$ and $n > 1$.

Comment: We know that we k = n, it is a SS. Is it true that it is not SS iff k < n ?

Comment: Well, as I said in the answer, condition on $X_1$, can you say that the joint distribution of $X_2, \cdots, X_n$ is independent of the parameter $\mu$? Take the simplest case $n=2$.